# Typing the properties of an anonymous object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, object, types, anonymous-objects

I've got a function:

```
function someFunction({ propertyA, propertyB })
{
  return 1;
}
```

I want to give the properties in the anonymous object in the argument to the function an explicit type, but using the typical TypeScript syntax for this (`propertyA: boolean`) would result in a type being put where value normally goes since the `:` in an object literal means 'the property on the left has the value on the right'.

I am wondering how I can do this? The compiler is giving me warnings about the properties implicitly having an `any` type. Apologies, this is probably quite basic but I've Googled around and looked on this site and can't find anything addressing this specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function someFunction({ propertyA, propertyB }: {propertyA: boolean; propertyB: number }){
    //...
```

or, better yet: make an explicit type:

```
interface SomeFunctionOpts{
    propertyA: boolean; 
    propertyB: number;
}

function someFunction({ propertyA, propertyB }: SomeFunctionOpts) {
    //...
```